# How does Flask use multiple methods in same route?

Tags: python, api, flask, crud

So, i'm writing a simple CRUD as it is in:

https://medium.com/@hillarywando/how-to-create-a-basic-crud-api-using-python-flask-cd68ef5fd7e3

and there you find these three methods:

`@app.route("/request", methods=['POST']) def postRequest():`

`@app.route('/request', methods=['GET']) def getRequest():`

`@app.route("/request", methods=['PUT']) def putRequest():`

While testing endpoints, something occourd me: in the example, GET, POST and PUT share the same route (/request), but when i enter "localhost:5000/request" on browser it only do the GET method.

I don't know if i made myself clear, but following the example above how does Flask or browser know which method to call, since there are three on the same route?

The same thing for GET and DELETE:

`@app.route('/request/<id>', methods=['GET']) def getRequestId(id):`

`@app.route('/request/<id>', methods=['DELETE']) def deleteRequest(id):`

How Flask or browser knows who to call? Or it is something that frontend should worry?

If it is frontend problem, how can i test all endpoints?

Thanks for the attencion

Tried to find the answer on google but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client (whether a browser, or something else) has to specify the method in the HTTP request. A browser will usually default to GET, but may have an extension that lets you choose the method for the request.

Other clients (curl, Postman, a library in a programming language, ...) will have ways to set the method.

Flask, when it receives the request, will call the appropriate function based on the path and method.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the current HTTP standard consists of a bunch of request methods, like `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE`. You can read the details in this [RFC standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html).

The client issues those requests meanwhile the server answers them.

Your browser is a type of `client` and a `Flask` program is one type of `server program`. When you open the tab and put in a URL, the automatic behavior for the browser is issuing a `GET` request by default. Hence your Flask program reads the header and body of this request and decides to route to the `GET` section of the code to answer it properly.

So what about other types of requests? One example of `PUT` would be, again, referring to the [RFC doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-10.1.1-7).

```bash
PUT /somewhere/fun HTTP/1.1
Host: origin.example.com
Content-Type: video/h264
Content-Length: 1234567890987
Expect: 100-continue
```

**Notice the *PUT* at the top of this request.**

Upon receiving this request, the Flask program checks the `PUT` word, and decides that it wants to handle the request by using the code `@app.route("/request", methods=['PUT'])` as you have written.

There are other awesome clients like `curl` (command line tool) or `postman` (GUI) available, they give you more visibility on what you have sent. Try them out, they are great. :）